# Pushkin's shortest poem's meaning

Tags: литература

If I naively translate

> Дай, Никита, мне одеться:
>   В митрополии звонят.
>     (*Александр Сергеевич Пушкин,  март 1821—1822*)

I cannot apreciate the literary value of these verses. Pushkin is said to have had a servant called precisely *Nikita*; then it makes sense he calls him to bring him clothes. Then I don't know what sort of place *митрополия* is, can it be precisely located? And could I translate the last line as *in (the) Metropolija sounds/they call*.? Or does it mean the *metropoly*, a specific big city?

Comment: Митрополия means a diocese headed by a митрополит, i. e., metropolitan archbishop. Also, in this particular case it means an office of a митрополит. Btw, this verse has a continuation.

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Might I ask which is the name of that complementary verses? (edit: I see, maybe the link in the answer).

Comment: Great job picking the right meaning for *Дай, Никита, мне одеться*! In modern Russian it would mean "let me dress up" (that is "stand aside and don't disturb me while I'm doing it").

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks for that valuable adding (as you can interpret from my question I thought, wrongly, it was the other way around).

Comment: @c.p.: "he calls him to bring him clothes" is what Pushkin meant (and I thought you interpreted it correctly this way). In modern (XXI century) Russian it's not used this way anymore except for *дай мне поесть* or *дай мне попить*.

Comment: @Quassnoi Thanks for this second correction. Я очень рад, узнать что-то новое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this source](http://www.friends-partners.org/friends/literature/19century/pushkin/givnikm.html(opt,mozilla,unix,russian,koi8,new)) Митрополия is a palace of митрополит (a head of church province) which also has a church:

> Митрополия - резиденция митрополита с церковью при ней.

In the document linked there are also other verses and comments to them.

Comment: So, that's not a poem by itself. It needs the whole text below, right?

Comment: In many sources these two verses exist by themselves. According to a document linked, these lines were added to all other lines based on memoires by В.П. Горчаков (Pushkin's friend), so I guess, without his evidence both parts of a poem in written form existed separately.

Comment: According to "А. С. Пушкин. Собрание сочинений в 10 томах.", "Дай, Никита, мне одеться" part is dated 1822 and "Раззевавшись от обедни" is dated 1821. But [this source](http://feb-web.ru/feb/pushkin/serial/v75/v75-020-.htm?cmd=0) claims that first two verses are indeed a part of a large poem.